# Showing $\dfrac{e^{-nx}}{n} < \epsilon$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I am trying to prove that $f_n(x)=\dfrac{e^{-nx}}{n}\rightarrow f(x)=0$ uniformly on $x\in[0, \infty)$. To do this I am trying to show that: $$\dfrac{e^{-nx}}{n} < \epsilon$$
I tried to do it this way, but I am not sure if it is correct:
\begin{align}
&\dfrac{e^{-nx}}{n} \\ 
&<\dfrac{1}{n} \quad \forall n>N_1 \ \exists N_1\in \mathbb{N} \\
&<\epsilon \quad \forall n>N_2 \ \exists N_2\in \mathbb{N} \\ \\
\therefore \dfrac{e^{-nx}}{n}&<\epsilon \quad \forall n>N=\max\{N_1, N_2\}
\end{align}

This in turn implies uniform convergence. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: The first inequality holds for $x\geq 0$. What is the domain of $f_n$?

Comment: Minor (yet important) remark: you should explicit where you have an uniform convergence (namely, on some set $]a,+\infty[$ for some $a>0$)

Comment: Oh sorry, the domain is $x\geq 0$, updated question accordingly

Comment: $\dfrac{e^{-nx}}{n}\leq \dfrac{1}{n}$ holds for all $x\geq 0$ and $n>0$, so no $N_1$ needed here. The rest is correct.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but how did you assume that $e^{-nx}<1$ for $x, n \geq 0$?

Comment: We know that $g(x)=e^x$ is an increasing function and $e^0=1$, so $e^{-nx}\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n \geq 1$ then $g(x)=e^{-nx}$ is a decreasing function defiend on $[0,+\infty)$

Thus $e^{-nx} \leq e^0=1$ thus $$\sup_{x \geq 0}|\frac{e^{-nx}}{n}| \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

Thus  is $\epsilon >0$ then for $n \geq n_0=[\frac{1}{\epsilon}]+1$ we have that $$ \sup_{x \geq 0}|\frac{e^{-nx}}{n}| \leq \epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to say

$$\frac{e^{-nx}}n\le\frac1n<\epsilon$$ for all $n>\dfrac1\epsilon$.

---

In fact, to prove uniform convergence, it suffices to say

$$\frac{e^{-nx}}n\le\frac1n\text{ and }\dfrac1n\text{ converges}.$$

Answer (score -1):

You got the idea.

Need to show that for $\epsilon >0$ there is a

$N \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that for $x \in [0,\infty)$ and

$n \gt N$ we have $|\dfrac{e^{-nx}}{n} -0| \lt \epsilon.$

$\dfrac{e^{-nx}}{n} =\dfrac{1}{ne^{nx}} =$

$\dfrac{1}{n(1+nx+(nx)^2/2!+...)} \le \dfrac{1}{n}.$

Archimedes :

There is a $N \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that

$N >1/\epsilon.$

For $x  \in [0,\infty )$ and $n >N$ we have

$\dfrac{e^{-nx}}{n} \le 1/n \lt 1/N \lt \epsilon.$